# Under what circumstances is the ARP table updated?

Tags: mac-address, arp

Lets say we have 3 devices in the same shared medium : A, B and C.

A wants to send a message to B, so before, it sends an ARP request as a broadcast message. When B receives it, it will update its ARP table with A's MAC address and send a unicast response. C also saw A's broadcast message, so it could also add A's MAC address.

Therefore, I think that A will end up having B's address in its ARP table and vice versa, but I am not sure about what happens with C.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> C also saw A's broadcast message, so it could also add A's MAC
> address.

That depends on the OS. By the RFC, C would only update its ARP table if an entry for A already existed in its ARP table.

*[RFC 826, An Ethernet Address Resolution Protocol -- or -- Converting Network Protocol Addresses to 48.bit Ethernet Address for Transmission on Ethernet Hardware](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc826)* has pseudocode for what is supposed tp happen, but different OSes (off-topic here) may do it differently:

> ### Packet Reception:
>
> When an address resolution packet is received, the receiving Ethernet
> module gives the packet to the Address Resolution module which goes
> through an algorithm similar to the following. Negative conditionals
> indicate an end of processing and a discarding of the packet.
>
> ```
> ?Do I have the hardware type in ar$hrd?
> Yes: (almost definitely)
>   [optionally check the hardware length ar$hln]
>   ?Do I speak the protocol in ar$pro?
>   Yes:
>     [optionally check the protocol length ar$pln]
>     Merge_flag := false
>     If the pair <protocol type, sender protocol address> is
>         already in my translation table, update the sender
>         hardware address field of the entry with the new
>         information in the packet and set Merge_flag to true.
>     ?Am I the target protocol address?
>     Yes:
>       If Merge_flag is false, add the triplet <protocol type,
>           sender protocol address, sender hardware address> to
>           the translation table.
>       ?Is the opcode ares_op$REQUEST?  (NOW look at the opcode!!)
>       Yes:
>         Swap hardware and protocol fields, putting the local
>             hardware and protocol addresses in the sender fields.
>         Set the ar$op field to ares_op$REPLY
>         Send the packet to the (new) target hardware address on
>             the same hardware on which the request was received.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Each ARP table entry is created or purged on its own. An ARP table entry is created when a host needs to send something to a layer-3 address for which there is no corresponding layer-2 address in the ARP table. An entry in an ARP table will time out and be purged after a period of non-use. It will be recreated the next time the host wants to send something to the layer-3 address.